# Which function grows faster $f(n)=(n \log n +1)^2 ,g(n)= (\log n +1)(n^2+1)$

Tags: limits, algorithms, asymptotics

$f(n)=(n \log n +1)^2 ,g(n)= (\log n +1)(n^2+1)$

If I must to solve this question by using limit, then answer will be too long

could I first simplify each function separately and find the big O of it then using the limit theorem ? or it cannot be done like this!??

if yes it would be like this

$\lim_{n \to \infty}=\dfrac{n^2log^2(n)}{n^2log(n)}$ so f(n) grow faster ?

Comment: Why not work with derivatives, you can prove that $f'(x)>g'(x)$ for all $x \in R$

Comment: Your method is correct, but notation is $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{n^2\log^2(n)}{n^2\log(n)} = \infty$$

Comment: Just calculate the limit of $f(n) /g(n) $ and it's not difficult.

Comment: Does that mean it's wrong if I first find the big theta separately for each function then calculate the limit of that big theat?? @ParamanandSingh

Comment: @NANA: it's not wrong. it means taking a long route instead of shorter one.